# .htaccess Redirect sub.DomainA to DomainB/Subdir Without Changing URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've thoroughly searched the net for an answer to this, w/o any luck.

I'm trying to write an htaccess redirects that does the following:

Redirect:

`subdomain.DomainA.com`

to:

`DomainB.com/subdir/`

But without changing the URL shown in the address bar, and keeping the direct links accessed to subdomain.DomainA.com

So `subdomain.DomainA.com/link/1000` becomes `DomainB.com/subdir/link/1000`

This is the most close I've been to, but I'm not yet able to nail it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.DomainA.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://DomainB.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

I've also tried `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://DomainB.com/subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [P]`, but this returns subdomain.DomainA.com/subdir for some reason :(

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you enable mod_proxy? Using P flag triggers the use of mod_proxy. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Comment: I've never seen REQUEST_URI used in a RewriteRule. It might be OK, but try the more normal: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://DomainB.com/$1 [P]

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above, when you use [P] you are effectively calling mod_proxy. You have to make it works before being able to use it in a rewrite rule. In fact, did you enable Proxy for the host you're trying to reach?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxy

```
<Proxy http://DomainB.com>
   Require all granted
</Proxy>
```

You could possibly increase your LogLevel (and/or) RewriteLogLevel to help debug why it's not working (I can't recall if the proxy deny was in the rewrite log or just plain error log)

Comment: mod_proxy.so is indeed loaded in the DomainB's Apache. Where should I put this? In the .htaccess of subdomain.DomainA.com?

Comment: I was calling [P] flag only because that is what I saw in some other examples, but I'm not really sure if that's necessary. Maybe there's another way?

Comment: This is the way to do rewrite to another external url without redirecting the user. (For which you would use [R])

Comment: This should be in the htaccess of domainA yes. You're telling apache it's allowed to proxy request to domainB.com for everyone (Kind of an open proxy but for only 1 domain).